# Change background color of an input when user clicks

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, addeventlistener

First of all, I think this question maybe is having an answer somewhere here on site and sorry for being repetitive but I can`t find what I want.

So... I have a form with 4 inputs, I want when someone clicks on the input to type in the value background color to be changed, and when the user clicks somewhere else to change it back to normal.
If anyone has multiple examples please write it down, I want to know more about how javascript works.

```
 <form>
                <div>
                    <label for="name">NAME</label>
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Please enter your name">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="company">COMPANY</label>
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="company" id="company"
                        placeholder="Leave it empty if you don`t have a name">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="phone">PHONE</label>
                    <input class="input"  type="text" name="phone" id="phone"
                        placeholder="Please,enter your mobile phone">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="email">EMAIL</label>
                    <input class="input" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email address">
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                    <label for="message">MESSAGE</label>
                    <textarea class="input" name="message" id="message" cols="54" rows="15"></textarea>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-large">Send</a>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`:focus` pseudo-class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) to apply CSS when the element is focused.

```css
input:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="name">NAME</label>
    <input class="input" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Please enter your name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="company">COMPANY</label>
    <input class="input" type="text" name="company" id="company" placeholder="Leave it empty if you don`t have a name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="phone">PHONE</label>
    <input class="input" type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Please,enter your mobile phone">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="email">EMAIL</label>
    <input class="input" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email address">
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    <label for="message">MESSAGE</label>
    <textarea class="input" name="message" id="message" cols="54" rows="15"></textarea>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-large">Send</a>
</form>
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you want to toggle between states on each click then you need to toggle(probably a class) based on click event.

Comment: This is definitely the best way to do it. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It works but after I click doesn`t come back to the original color

Comment: @ConstantinCT : ok then need to use click event listener..... ok when you focused to another input do you want to persist state of existing or want to change?

Comment: Guyss..sorry was having something bad in my code that`s why the color was not coming back. Thank you alll!!!!!!!